# how to get the inserted table row?

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck on this, can you help on how to get the inserted `tr` in javascript. And I want to `trigger('click')` the file input.

```
$('html').on('click', '.add_image_fieldset', function(event) {
    var currentTR;
    currentTR = $(this).closest('tr').before("<tr><td><input type='file'/></td></tr>");
    currentTR.children('td').children('input').trigger('click');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

But the code above is not getting the inserted `tr`.

Please help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What inserted `<tr>`? The only elements you are adding are a `<td>` and an `<input>`.

Comment: I wouldn't use a '$' prefix for variable names as they're an alias for jQuery

Comment: @alpadev — Using a `$` *prefix* for a variable name that holds HTML elements in a jQuery object is a very common convention.

Comment: @Quentin wow okay, never seen that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `before` is the *same* jQuery object. It is not a *new* object representing the content you inserted.

Create the variable first. Add it to the DOM second.

```
var currentTR = $("<tr><td><input type='file'/></td></tr>");
$(this).closest('tr').before(currentTR);
```

Comment: Thank you for this!